# How to set ef core foreign key field not null?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities in ef core,

```
public class Post
{
    // ... Some properties

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets post platform.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Platform Platform { get; set; }


    //... More properties
}

 public class Platform
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets platform name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets platform id.
    /// </summary>
    public string Version { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets platform logo url.
    /// </summary>
    public string LogoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

and then i added migrations to database ,

The issue is in database it has relationship from post table to platform table via `PlatformId` but that column allows null,

Can any one point me what is the issue with this , i need to avoid nulls for this relationship.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: [Required and Optional Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Foreign Key to your model as well, and use that to control whenever it allows null or not.

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(PlatformId))]
public virtual Platform Platform { get; set; }
public Guid PlatformId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Just to slightly extend, if it were `public int? PlatformId` the FK would be nullable.

Comment: Id is UUID and not null

Comment: @NIsd,

Adding Platform to post class also adding foriegn key!

Comment: @Roshan: EF adds the FK itself when it sees the nav prop (which it does in your code), but EF cannot understand whether you want nullability or not (since all classes are inherently nullable). Therefore it adds nullability. If you want to disable nullability, you can do so by explicitly stating whether the FK's type (`Guid` in your case) is nullable or not (as value types are _not_ nullable by default but can be made nullable explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a field not to be null then add attribute `[Required]`:

```
[Required]
public Guid PlatformId { get; set; }
```

or you may read link by Ivan Stoev in comments for entity framework fluent

Comment: This is the way to do it but for me it helped to understand that you may need to explicitly add the PlatformID property to the Post model to allow you to decorate it with [Required]. (EF will add it to the table def anyway, whether you include it in your model or not). It's a shame you can't just added it to the Platform property (or use .IsRequired() in the model builder) but hey-ho!